# How to display a string received with an intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I was about to go through the Training on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), to learn how to pass an intent with an EXTRA (a string in this case) to another activity and display it in that second activity. From the Training I understood how to create and pass on the intent, but not how to display the EXTRA-string, as there were two methods used (to configure the displaying of the string) which gave an error in android-studio (this is from the second activity):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);

setContentView(textView);
}
```

setTextSize as well as setText give the following error:

```
non-static method setText(CharSequence) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Despite that I don´t surely know what excactly that means, I tried to display the string in another way:

```
private TextView ausgabe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    ausgabe.setText(message);
    TextView.setText(message);
    setContentView(ausgabe);

}
```

Is this even possible - and if so, how do I accomplish that the string eventually gets displayed?

In order to give some additional context, here is the implementation in the first activity, I used to create the intent:

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.my_very_own.myapplication.MESSAGE";

public void sendMessage(View view){
Intent intent= new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message= editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

I also figured, it could possibly be a java error - changed the jdk form 7 to 8 for that matter but apparently that didn´t help.

I would highly appreaciate a proposal to attain this, admittedly basic, task, as I searched the web for hours and couldn´t find the crucial part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TextView.setText(message);

You can't directly `setText(..)` to `TextView Widget`. You need to create Object of `TextView` and then apply `textView_Object.setText(message);` to `Object`.

Like so

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line -

```
TextView.setText(message);
```

:)

Answer (score -1):

### Try this

**FirstActivity.java class**

```
    {
     // pass string value from first activity to second activity
    Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Message", searchKey);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**SecondActivity.class**

```
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // get intent value 
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    strMessage = intent.getStringExtra("Message");

    textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    textView.setText(strMessage);
    }
```

Comment: `textView` is  `NULL`.